# How do I deal with a network

Tags: networking

A 1000 byte packet is sent over a 50 kilo- bits-per-second (Kbps) point-to-point link whose propagation delay is 10 msec. The packet will reach the destination after msec (Assume 1K 1000)

Comment: I think you missed to ask the question here

Answer (score 0):

1 Byte = 8 Bits

=> 1000 Bytes = 1000*8 = 8000 Bits = 8 Kilo Bytes

Speed  = 50 kilo bytes per sec

Time = 8/50  Sec

= (8 * 100)/50 msec

= 8  * 20  msec

= 160 msec

Delay of 10 msec

The packet will reach the destination after 160 + 10 = **170 msec**

Answer (score -1):

this is the answer for your question 10msec+(1000x8)/50K=170msec